# cannot produce messages to kafka when running in kubernetes cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes

I am trying to run kafka inside kubernetes cluster. I am using the incubator helm chart to deploy kafka and zookeeper, I am deploying with no extra parameters - basically it is kafka cluster of 3 nodes. However when I am trying to connect using my application , it is failing while it was working perfectly when i run it inside docker swarm using the Confluent image. I am getting an error of

> 2018-07-11 19:25:16 WARN  {org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient processDisconnection} - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=rest-to-kafka-consumer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

first i have tried that those will be the properties for the producer

```
new Properties()
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, EnvVariables.brokerEndpoint.get)
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all")
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "0")
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, "16384")
props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "1")
props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, "33554432")
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
```

where EnvVariables.brokerEndpoint.get is the kafka service`kubectl get svc -n occm
NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
occm-kafka                      ClusterIP      10.31.241.149   <none>           9092/TCP                     3d`

after that i have changed the configuration to connect using zookeeper - but still i am getting the same error

```
new Properties()
props.put("zookeeper.connect", EnvVariables.brokerEndpoint.get)
props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "100000")
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all")
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "0")
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, "16384")
props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "1")
props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, "33554432")
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
```

what do I need to change? using the test client of the sh files works fine

Comment: `EnvVariables.brokerEndpoint` resolves to the correct addresses? Can you show the Kafka server properties? And that definitely won't work for Zookeeper connection

Comment: Is your application running inside the Kubernetes cluster on a separate pod or it's running outside? Are you running Kubernetes using minikube ?

Comment: Could you share YAML files that describe your Kafka on Kubernetes setup? What address and port are you using to connect Kafka from your application? I can guess it could be incorrect configuration of kafka Service object.